# Transform raster CRS fails

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I have a large amount of .TIF which come in EPSG 31467. I want to transform them into EPSG 3044. My gdalwarp command throws me various errors, no matter what I try:

```
gdalwarp - s_srs EPSG:31467 -t_srs EPSG:3044 infile.tif outfile.tif
```

throws:
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for .\infile.tif. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.

If I try then:

```
 gdalwarp - s_srs EPSG:31467 -t_srs EPSG:3044 -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM
```

I get completely unusable files. Any idea how to transform those .tif's ?

Comment: Have you tried transforming a single file using the QGIS GUI? Have you studied the [GDAl-options](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)?

Comment: Remove first the space from `- s_srs EPSG:31467` and see if it works with correct -s_srs parameter.

Comment: @Erik how can i see what qgis passes to gdal when i export a tif and change the crs there?

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the hint, but it did not change the result :/

Comment: At the bottom of the transform-raster-GUI there's a text window which shows what you're ticking on/off @sn1ks

Comment: ah well, creating a valid .tfw file for the source crs helped, thank you for your suggestions though!

Comment: I would have asked you to add gdalinfo report from the  source image next.